# session variable not updating

Tags: php, session

please check my code below.when I logout does not save in my logout column in mysql.

```
$query = $DBcon->query("UPDATE logs SET logout = now() WHERE id={$_SESSION['userSession']}");
```

but when I changed to

```
$query = $DBcon->query("UPDATE logs SET logout = now() WHERE id='12'");
```

it works.

Thank you guys.

Comment: do you have `session_start();`on this page?

Comment: I think that you don't have `session_start();` in top of the page or `session_destory();` / `unset($_SESSION['userSession']);` before the update sql.

Comment: $query = $DBcon->query("UPDATE logs SET logout = now() WHERE id={$_SESSION['userSession']}"); 
 mysqli_query($query);

session_destroy();
unset($_SESSION['userSession']);
 header("Location: login.php");

Comment: `$_SESSION['userSession']` is not quoted in the first example. Is that really an integer? What does error reporting tell you, or what is the real query?

Comment: My problem is i dont know the correct code for session variable. I put this code it works. $query = $DBcon->query("UPDATE logs SET logout = now() WHERE id='12'");

Comment: Yes, you've said that. Please provide more information.

Comment: thanx chris85. no error does not update in my logout column.

Comment: Whats the actual query? Please update the question with your code.

Comment: $query = $DBcon->query("UPDATE logs SET logout = now() WHERE id={$_SESSION['userSession']}"); 
 mysqli_query($query); When I run the code its not working probably the problem is in the {$_SESSION['userSession']}. 

if (isset($_GET['logout'])) {
session_destroy();
unset($_SESSION['userSession']);

Comment: Post the **actual** query. `var_dump("UPDATE logs SET logout = now() WHERE id={$_SESSION['userSession']}");` or `echo "UPDATE logs SET logout = now() WHERE id={$_SESSION['userSession']}";` or `print_r("UPDATE logs SET logout = now() WHERE id={$_SESSION['userSession']}");`

Answer (score 1):

You need a `session_start();` (at the top of script) before using `$_SESSION` related stuff; Try this :

```
    if(session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE){
        session_start();
    }
    require_once 'dbconnect.php';


    if (!isset($_SESSION['userSession'])) {
        header("Location: login.php");

    }else if(isset($_SESSION['userSession'])!=""){
        header("Location: index.php");
    }

   if(isset($_GET['logout'])) {
      $query = $DBcon->query("UPDATE logs SET logout = now() WHERE id=  {$_SESSION['userSession']}");

    mysqli_query($query);

    unset($_SESSION['userSession']);
    session_destroy();
    header("Location: login.php");
}
```

Comment: Yes I put the session_start(); please see my code. <?php
session_start();
require_once 'dbconnect.php';
if (!isset($_SESSION['userSession'])) {     
 header("Location: login.php");
} else if (isset($_SESSION['userSession'])!="") {
 header("Location: index.php");
}

Comment: <?php
session_start();
require_once 'dbconnect.php';
if (!isset($_SESSION['userSession'])) {     
 header("Location: login.php");
} else if (isset($_SESSION['userSession'])!="") {
 header("Location: index.php");
}

if (isset($_GET['logout'])) {

session_destroy();
unset($_SESSION['userSession']);
 $query = $DBcon->query("UPDATE logs SET logout = now() WHERE id={$_SESSION['userSession']}"); 
 mysqli_query($query);


 header("Location: login.php");
}

 


?>

Comment: its not working I tried your code but when I changed the  WHERE id=  {$_SESSION['userSession']} to  WHERE id= '2'. It works.

Comment: var_dump({$_SESSION['userSession']} ) to see its content; and show the output

Comment: below this line if(isset($_GET['logout'])) {

Comment: Ok.I'll try.thanx.